Import ECW file
is it possible to add an ecw file as a data source?
I have the gdal extension installed:
Module Name: ImageI/O-Ext GDAL Coverage Extension
Module ID: gs-gdal
Version: 2.24.2
Component: GridCoverage2DReader
Message:
JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: 3.0.0
GDAL Version: 3.0.4
GDAL Release Date: 20200128
GDAL Build Info: PAM_ENABLED=YES
OGR_ENABLED=YES
GEOS_ENABLED=YES
GEOS_VERSION=3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1
ImageIO-Ext Version: 1.4.7
Geoserver image version: kartoza/geoserver:2.24.2
I still don't have the option to import a file from ecw:

gdalinfo --formats
Supported Formats:
VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
DERIVED -raster- (ro): Derived datasets using VRT pixel functions
GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
RPFTOC -raster- (rovs): Raster Product Format TOC format
ECRGTOC -raster- (rovs): ECRG TOC format
HFA -raster- (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
SAR_CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS SAR Image
CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS Image
JAXAPALSAR -raster- (rov): JAXA PALSAR Product Reader (Level 1.1/1.5)
GFF -raster- (rov): Ground-based SAR Applications Testbed File Format (.gff)
ELAS -raster- (rw+v): ELAS
AIG -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Binary Grid
AAIGrid -raster- (rwv): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
GRASSASCIIGrid -raster- (rov): GRASS ASCII Grid
SDTS -raster- (rov): SDTS Raster
DTED -raster- (rwv): DTED Elevation Raster
PNG -raster- (rwv): Portable Network Graphics
JPEG -raster- (rwv): JPEG JFIF
MEM -raster- (rw+): In Memory Raster
JDEM -raster- (rov): Japanese DEM (.mem)
GIF -raster- (rwv): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
BIGGIF -raster- (rov): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
ESAT -raster- (rov): Envisat Image Format
FITS -raster- (rw+): Flexible Image Transport System
BSB -raster- (rov): Maptech BSB Nautical Charts
XPM -raster- (rwv): X11 PixMap Format
BMP -raster- (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
DIMAP -raster- (rov): SPOT DIMAP
AirSAR -raster- (rov): AirSAR Polarimetric Image
RS2 -raster- (rovs): RadarSat 2 XML Product
SAFE -raster- (rov): Sentinel-1 SAR SAFE Product
PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
PCRaster -raster- (rw+): PCRaster Raster File
ILWIS -raster- (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
SGI -raster- (rw+v): SGI Image File Format 1.0
SRTMHGT -raster- (rwv): SRTMHGT File Format
Leveller -raster- (rw+v): Leveller heightfield
Terragen -raster- (rw+v): Terragen heightfield
GMT -raster- (rw): GMT NetCDF Grid Format
netCDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Network Common Data Format
HDF4 -raster- (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
HDF4Image -raster- (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
ISIS3 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 3)
ISIS2 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
PDS -raster- (rov): NASA Planetary Data System
PDS4 -raster,vector- (rw+vs): NASA Planetary Data System 4
VICAR -raster- (rov): MIPL VICAR file
TIL -raster- (rov): EarthWatch .TIL
ERS -raster- (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
L1B -raster- (rovs): NOAA Polar Orbiter Level 1b Data Set
FIT -raster- (rwv): FIT Image
GRIB -raster- (rwv): GRIdded Binary (.grb, .grb2)
RMF -raster- (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
WCS -raster- (rovs): OGC Web Coverage Service
WMS -raster- (rwvs): OGC Web Map Service
MSGN -raster- (rov): EUMETSAT Archive native (.nat)
RST -raster- (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
INGR -raster- (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
GSAG -raster- (rwv): Golden Software ASCII Grid (.grd)
GSBG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
GS7BG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
COSAR -raster- (rov): COSAR Annotated Binary Matrix (TerraSAR-X)
TSX -raster- (rov): TerraSAR-X Product
COASP -raster- (ro): DRDC COASP SAR Processor Raster
R -raster- (rwv): R Object Data Store
MAP -raster- (rov): OziExplorer .MAP
KMLSUPEROVERLAY -raster- (rwv): Kml Super Overlay
WEBP -raster- (rwv): WEBP
PDF -raster,vector- (rw+vs): Geospatial PDF
Rasterlite -raster- (rwvs): Rasterlite
MBTiles -raster,vector- (rw+v): MBTiles
PLMOSAIC -raster- (ro): Planet Labs Mosaics API
CALS -raster- (rwv): CALS (Type 1)
WMTS -raster- (rwv): OGC Web Map Tile Service
SENTINEL2 -raster- (rovs): Sentinel 2
MRF -raster- (rw+v): Meta Raster Format
PNM -raster- (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
DOQ1 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (Old Style)
DOQ2 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (New Style)
PAux -raster- (rw+v): PCI .aux Labelled
MFF -raster- (rw+v): Vexcel MFF Raster
MFF2 -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
FujiBAS -raster- (rov): Fuji BAS Scanner Image
GSC -raster- (rov): GSC Geogrid
FAST -raster- (rov): EOSAT FAST Format
BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
LAN -raster- (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
CPG -raster- (rov): Convair PolGASP
IDA -raster- (rw+v): Image Data and Analysis
NDF -raster- (rov): NLAPS Data Format
EIR -raster- (rov): Erdas Imagine Raw
DIPEx -raster- (rov): DIPEx
LCP -raster- (rwv): FARSITE v.4 Landscape File (.lcp)
GTX -raster- (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
LOSLAS -raster- (rov): NADCON .los/.las Datum Grid Shift
NTv1 -raster- (rov): NTv1 Datum Grid Shift
NTv2 -raster- (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
CTable2 -raster- (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
ACE2 -raster- (rov): ACE2
SNODAS -raster- (rov): Snow Data Assimilation System
KRO -raster- (rw+v): KOLOR Raw
ROI_PAC -raster- (rw+v): ROI_PAC raster
RRASTER -raster- (rw+v): R Raster
BYN -raster- (rw+v): Natural Resources Canada's Geoid
ARG -raster- (rwv): Azavea Raster Grid format
RIK -raster- (rov): Swedish Grid RIK (.rik)
USGSDEM -raster- (rwv): USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)
GXF -raster- (rov): GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format
DODS -raster- (ro): DAP 3.x servers
BAG -raster- (rwv): Bathymetry Attributed Grid
HDF5 -raster- (rovs): Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
HDF5Image -raster- (rov): HDF5 Dataset
NWT_GRD -raster- (rw+v): Northwood Numeric Grid Format .grd/.tab
NWT_GRC -raster- (rov): Northwood Classified Grid Format .grc/.tab
ADRG -raster- (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
SRP -raster- (rovs): Standard Raster Product (ASRP/USRP)
BLX -raster- (rwv): Magellan topo (.blx)
EPSILON -raster- (rwv): Epsilon wavelets
PostGISRaster -raster- (rws): PostGIS Raster driver
SAGA -raster- (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat, .sg-grd-z)
IGNFHeightASCIIGrid -raster- (rov): IGN France height correction ASCII Grid
XYZ -raster- (rwv): ASCII Gridded XYZ
HF2 -raster- (rwv): HF2/HFZ heightfield raster
JPEGLS -raster- (rwv): JPEGLS
OZI -raster- (rov): OziExplorer Image File
CTG -raster- (rov): USGS LULC Composite Theme Grid
E00GRID -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
ZMap -raster- (rwv): ZMap Plus Grid
NGSGEOID -raster- (rov): NOAA NGS Geoid Height Grids
IRIS -raster- (rov): IRIS data (.PPI, .CAPPi etc)
PRF -raster- (rov): Racurs PHOTOMOD PRF
RDA -raster- (ro): DigitalGlobe Raster Data Access driver
EEDAI -raster- (ros): Earth Engine Data API Image
DAAS -raster- (ro): Airbus DS Intelligence Data As A Service driver
SIGDEM -raster- (rwv): Scaled Integer Gridded DEM .sigdem
GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
CAD -raster,vector- (rovs): AutoCAD Driver
PLSCENES -raster,vector- (ro): Planet Labs Scenes API
NGW -raster,vector- (rw+s): NextGIS Web
GenBin -raster- (rov): Generic Binary (.hdr Labelled)
ENVI -raster- (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
EHdr -raster- (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
ISCE -raster- (rw+v): ISCE raster
HTTP -raster,vector- (ro): HTTP Fetching Wrapper


does your GDAL have ECW support compiled in? gdalinfo --formats will show it

@IanTurton gdalinfo --formats does not have the ECW format

Then you have not installed the ECW libraries needed with GDAL to access them so GeoServer will not be able to load ECW files

@IanTurton How to install it if I use GeoServer in Docker and it already has gdal but without ECW?

You will need to modify the docker container to either download or build a gdal with ECW included.
